# Blank terminal on ubuntu 18

Tags: command-line, bashrc

I tried to add an alias in the bash but I think I deleted something as I now can't see no user in my terminal..

I did `vim ~/.bashrc`
Then `e` to edit the file and edited on the last line where I added an alias.

Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> and `:wq` , but then my terminal was blank...

Anyway to fix this??

Comment: Can you update your question adding a bit more info? Which steps did you take trying to add the alias?

Comment: Ok, one second.